# CakePHP: How to disable email online validation?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and the email rule validates that the email has a valid host name or so. This is great, I like this feature, but it does not make things easy when testing on a local server, specially if it's offline.

Is there anyway to disable this very quick? A config variable maybe?

EDIT: Not going model by model changing the rule variable, but a global config variable.

Comment: This clearly explained in the CakePHP book under email validation.

Comment: Its hard to remember everything... Rather, some people are expert on Cakephp but other people are expert on their subject... So, A quick way to know simple thing is SO....

Comment: @FazalRasel - it sounds like you're suggesting not doing your own  research, even in the clearly-written documentation.  Why do any work on your own when you just ask here so other people can do the work for you.  That's not the point of SO IMO. Feel free to disagree.

Comment: @Dave Thanks, you're right. I meant a config variable to change quicker this specific rule validation, not going model by model changing this on each file. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  Have removed my down-vote.  Look forward to an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove second arguments from rule-- Like you defined as

```
'rule' => array('email', true)
```

This should be as-

```
'rule' => array('email')
```

#### after edit on question

You can do this by dynamic validation. But the easy approach will be unset email validation thus you are on development environment..

## AppModel.php

```
public function beforeValidate(){
                   if$this->validate['email'](){
                     unset($this->validate['email']);
                   }
             // now, If you really need to check email add dynamic rule for email field here.
}
```

Comment: thanks, I know this, I meant a way to change this quicker than going model by model ie. using the `Config/core.php` file.

Comment: You could create your own validation method which wraps the core email rule passing `$deep` based on whatever you want.

Comment: I didn't want to remove the email validation but just the host verification. I did use your code changing how the email rule is declared. Thanks, this was useful.